# use StreamBuilder with collectionrefrence as snapshot in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I'm new to flutter and I'm trying to retrieve a list of categories from the firebase cloud firestore into my flutter application using `StreamBuilder`.
Im using `flutter 2.8.0` and `cloud_firestore: ^3.1.7`
this my firestore documents: [categories collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2Qpp.png)
here is my code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:harfanah/shared/loading.dart';

class categoriesMod extends StatefulWidget {
  const categoriesMod({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _categoriesModState createState() => _categoriesModState();
}

class _categoriesModState extends State<categoriesMod> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold (
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('categories').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if(!snapshot.hasData) {
            return loading();
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: ,
            itemBuilder: ,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm really confused about how can I use `ItemCount` and `ItemBuilder`. I found many many solution that say i should use something like this: `itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length` but it does not work. data does not even have any attributes other than these: [data attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGEPv.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the type of the `StreamBuilder` then you can use the properties/methods available in the class `QuerySnapshot`:

```dart
class _categoriesModState extends State<categoriesMod> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold (
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>>>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('categories').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if(!snapshot.hasData) {
             return loading();
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context,index){
              return ListTile(
                title: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()["code"],
                leading: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()["name"],
              );
            } ,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```